# Hyperledger Composer 0.15.0 sharing network with the local Playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I was wondering if since the 0.15.0 release and switching to cards someone has figured out how to access the same network both locally via the CLI and in the Playground and with the same Fabric runtime.
So far, I have been able to install my network's runtime, start and ping it on the Playground's fabric after creating PeerAdmin card  using the script that came with Playground.
However, importing the newly deployed network's admin card fails in the Playground. If, however, I deploy the network via the Playground, export the admin card, download/import the admin card from the Playground and then try to composer ping it, it just sits there timing out after a while.    This is MacOS High Sierra. So what gives and what can be done?
Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your issue correctly, this is how you can solve it:

1. Create your business network in Playground
2. Export business network card from Playground (download button on card) which produces `{nameOfUser}.card` file.
3. Now you transfer this card to wherever you have installed fabric/playground
4. Run command: `composer card import -f {nameOfUser}.card`
5. Now your business card should appear under location  {usersHome}/.composer/cards/user@network-name
6. Inside /cards folder, you should see 2 folders. One is "PeerAdmin" which was created if you followed setup and another one is your imported one
7. Copy `connection.json` from "PeerAdmin" to your new card and replace it. **(this is most important step)**
8. Run command: `composer-rest-server` and use as network card: user@network-name - folder that you copied

With all this steps I successfully created and ran server. Now you can access it on port IP:3000/explorer

Answer (score 0):

You **can** share the Business Network Cards between Playground and the CLI. However it can be a bit more difficult if you are running Playground in a Docker Container.

With the CLI you connect to your Fabric servers on **localhost** and Docker deals with the Port fowarding into the Containers for the Fabric.

The Fabric Containers (and the Playground if you start it in a container) connect with eachother on 'fake' addresses managed by docker-compose e.g. **orderer.example.com:7050**

So if you start `composer-playground` using the CLI any Card you export will have localhost as the addresses of Fabric servers and other CLI commands will be able to utilise it.  If however you are using Playground in a container the Card will use the fake addresses and you will not be able to connect from the CLI straightaway.

I assume you are using Playground in a Container and hence having the problem.  If you find the `connection.json` in a location similar to: `~/.composer/cards/admin@*xxxxxx*/connection.json` and edit the addresses of the fabric server to be localhost you should be able to use the CLI as expected.

Comment: Thank you!  Makes perfect sense. I totally missed  the local playground. What worked was deploying in the CLI, and then importing the PeerAdmin and the network's admin into Playground.  Still have to try out the container solution from  loki19's post. cheers.